# google compute engine ssh is very slow and then timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to login into google compute engine VM instance.

```
$ gcloud compute ssh gke-kubia-default-pool-5af12345-abcd --zone=us-east1-b
```

It took very long time and then gave resulted in the below error.

```
ssh: connect to host b.b.c.d port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I tried to login in my mac terminal as well as browser terminal in web interface.
Any idea, how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have a firewall rule that permits ingress connections on port 22.
The default rule looks like this
***default-allow-ssh Ingress    Apply to all    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:22 Allow   1000    default***

If you don't see it under

- VPC Network
- Firewall rules

You can create it by running:  `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules create mySSH --allow tcp:22 --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0`

I would also try to test the connection by running:

```
$ telnet IP 22
```

---

**EDIT => additional info:**

- For some tips on SSH troubleshooting you can have a look at [**this
  guide**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/).
- There is this [**StackOverflow thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001519/cannot-access-vm-using-gcloud-compute/49012827#49012827) that might be helpful as
  well.