# Why am I Unable to Access a Google Compute Engine VM?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I am unable to access a Google Compute Engine (GCE) VM (`$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`) with the Google Cloud SDK (`gcloud`):

```sh
gcloud compute \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID \
ssh \
--zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE \
$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME

#=>

Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I tried:

1. revoking SSH keys:

   ```sh
   gcloud auth revoke --all
   ```
2. ```sh
   gcloud auth login
   ```
3. to access `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME` again with:

   ```sh
   gcloud compute \
   --project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID \
   ssh \
   --zone=$GCE_INSTANCE_ZONE \
   $GCE_INSTANCE_NAME

   #=>

   ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
    - Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects
   ```

What steps can I take in order to successfully `ssh` into `$GCE_INSTANCE_NAME`?

Answer (score 4):

> Permission denied (publickey). ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

This error seems to refer to some error with the SSH keys or an incomplete Linux Guest environment.

I'm wondering what is the purpose on running `gcloud auth revoke --all`

Can you provide the output of the following commands?

1. `$ gcloud compute instances describe name-of-your-instance --zone

   zone-the-instance-is-in --project name-of-your-project`
2. `$ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output name-of-your-instance
   --zone zone-the-instance-is-in --project name-of-your-project`
3. `$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project name-of-your-project`

The commands can be helpful because:

1. With this command we can check the **state of the ssh keys** on the
   instance and the scopes that are enabled in the instance (along with
   other info)
2. This command provides the **[serial output log entries](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/instances/tail-serial-port-output)** from the instance that **can help troubleshoot the connection issues** you're experiencing. Note that this logs are wiped after a reboot of the instance so don't expect persistent logs here, but this info can be useful for your case.
3. This command outputs the **[firewall rules](http://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)** within your project; there should be a default or curated firewall rule allowing TCP ingress traffic on port 22, if not (you'll need to create one).

Have you tried [**to SSH from the browser**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser) in incognito mode? 
Sometimes, browser extensions can prevent the normal functioning of the SSH over the browser feature, that's why I recommend the incognito mode.

---

**EDIT**
In order to make this **post useful** (and easier to read) for the community I'm summarizing here some of the comments from below:

**Error shown:**

> Could not fetch resource: - Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects//zones//instances/

**What to do:** Check the user roles/permissions

```
$ gcloud beta iam roles list --account your-account-here

> --- description: Full management of App Engine apps (but not storage).
> etag: AA== name: roles/appengine.appAdmin stage: GA title: App Engine Admin
> --- description: Ability to view App Engine app status. etag: AA== name: roles/appengine.appViewer stage: GA title: App Engine Viewer
```

**From the output above:** the user has only App Engine permissions (but not permissions in Compute Engine)

**What to do:** ask the project owner to add a role that grants the user access to the GCE instances (Instance Admin Role, Compute Admin Role)
List of the available roles here: [cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#instance_admin_role](http://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#instance_admin_role)

Required info, run 2 commands:

- in order to check the **log** from the instance:

  $ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output name-of-your-instance --zone zone-the-instance-is-in --project name-of-your-project

  > SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20180102_145157-google) Total RAM Size = 0x000000006cc00000 = 1740 MiB CPUs found: 1 Max CPUs supported:
  >   256 found virtio-scsi at 0:3 virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
  >   virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520 = 10240 MiB drive 0x000f2330: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
  >   Booting from Hard Disk 0... [ 0.000000]
  >   Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset [ 0.000000]
  >   Initializing cgroup subsys cpu [ 0.000000]
  >   Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct [ 0.000000]
  >   Linux version 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd
- to confirm there's a **firewall rule** allowing ingress traffic on port 22:

  $ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project name-of-your-project
  NAME                NETWORK   DIRECTION   PRIORITY  ALLOW
  default-allow-ssh   default   INGRESS     65534     tcp:22

From the **output above** the **firewall rule allowing SSH traffic** has **priority 65534**.
Priority is an integer from 0 to 65535, both inclusive.
Lower value of priority implies higher precedence.
In other words, 1 is higher priority than 2.
You can read **[this document](http://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls)** for further explanation

Update the firewall rule to set a higher priority.
To do so run the command:

```
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules update --priority 1000 default-allow-ssh
```

**Issue:** I tried to SSH into the instance I still got the same old error : ssh: connect to host X.XX.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255]

Check if the **ssh service** is **running in the instance**. 
Run the following command to get the IP of the instance:

```
$ gcloud compute instances describe [NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE] --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'
```

**Install netcat** => is a computer networking utility for reading/writing to network connections:

```
$ sudo apt-get install netcat
```

**Run** the following command to check the output of the command:

```
$ nc [EXTERNAL_IP] 22 
>
```

**Issue:** Nothing is returned from running nc [EXTERNAL_IP] 22

**Check** if the **Linux Guest Environment is enabled** in your instance. 
To do so, you should add an startup script on the GCE instance. 
To add the startup script to the instance:

1. Click on the instance name
2. Click on edit
3. Go to the "custom metadata" section
4. In the "Key" text field add: startup-script
5. In the "Value" text field add: `#! /bin/bash sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep google | grep enabled`
6. Save the changes

[**More detailed info on startup scripts**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) is also available.

Then restart the instance so to allow the script to execute. 
**Verify that the Linux Guest Environment scripts are installed and running**. 
To do so, check the output of the startup script in the serial log console from the GCE instance. 
You can check [**the expected outputs for the different Operating Systems**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#wgei_services).

**If the Linux Guest Environment is not installed, re-install it**. 
You can follow [**this documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#installation_methods) to install the LGE.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Here is the result of the command: 
1. ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.describe) Could not fetch resource:
 - Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects/<Project-Name>/zones/<Zone-Name>/instances/<Instance-Name>'

2. ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.get-serial-port-output) Could not fetch serial port output: Required 'projects/<Project-Name>/zones/<Zone-Name>/instances/<Instance-Name>'

3. ERROR: (gcloud.compute.firewall-rules.list) Some requests did not succeed:
 - Required 'compute.firewalls.list' permission for 'projects/<Project-Name>'

Comment: The user you use to run the commands does not have permissions within the GCE instance.
Is the user you are using the owner of the project?

Comment: Can you provide the output of this command to see what are the current permissions your user has?

$ gcloud beta iam roles list --account your-account-here

Comment: ---
description: Full management of App Engine apps (but not storage).
etag: AA==
name: roles/appengine.appAdmin
stage: GA
title: App Engine Admin
---
description: Ability to view App Engine app status.
etag: AA==
name: roles/appengine.appViewer
stage: GA
title: App Engine Viewer
---

Comment: I ran this command: gcloud compute --project project-name ssh --zone name-zone name-of-instance

Here is the result:
ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Comment: From the output you've provided, it seems that the account you're using has only App Engine Admin role, so with this role you won't be able to SSH into the VM instances. You need to ask the project owner to add a role that grants you access to the GCE instances, like Instance Admin Role or Compute Admin Role I link the documentation here for reference: cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#instance_admin_role You can check a list of the available roles here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute_engine_roles

Comment: Thanks for the note. You were right I miss some role. So I add roles: compute Admin, compute instance admin (beta), compute instance admin(v1). I save the change. I run the command gcloud compute --project "project-name" ssh --zone "zone-name" "instance-name". But I still have this error: ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Comment: Please provide the output of the commands 1 and 2 requested on my answer since now the account you're using has the right roles.

Here are the commands you should run:

$ gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output name-of-your-instance --zone zone-the-instance-is-in --project name-of-your-project

$ gcloud compute firewall-rules list --project name-of-your-project

Comment: SeaBIOS (version 1.8.2-20180102_145157-google)
Total RAM Size = 0x000000006cc00000 = 1740 MiB
CPUs found: 1     Max CPUs supported: 256
found virtio-scsi at 0:3
virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0
virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520 = 10240 MiB
drive 0x000f2330: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520
Booting from Hard Disk 0...
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd

Comment: here is the output of the second command:
NAME                    NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW                         DENY
db                      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:27017,udp:27017
default                 default  INGRESS    1000                                    all
default-allow-http      default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-icmp      default  INGRESS    65534     icmp

Comment: default-allow-internal  default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:0-65535,udp:0-65535,icmp
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:22
http1                   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
vnc-server              default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5901

To show all fields of the firewall, please show in JSON format: --format=json
To show all fields in table format, please see the examples in --help.

Comment: From the output you've provided the firewall rule allowing SSH traffic has priority 65534.

Priority is an integer from 0 to 65535, both inclusive. Lower value of priority implies higher precedence. In other words, 1 is higher priority than 2. You can read this document for further explanation https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls

You can try updating the firewall rule to set a higher priority.
To do so run the command:
$ gcloud compute firewall-rules update --priority 1000 default-allow-ssh

Then try to ssh into the instance and let us know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the note. I change the priority of the SSH here is part of the result: default-allow-https     default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:443
default-allow-rdp       default  INGRESS    65534     tcp:3389
default-allow-ssh       default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22
http1                   default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:80
vnc-server              default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:5901

Comment: when I tried to SSH into the instance I still got the same old error : ssh: connect to host X.XX.XX.XX port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].

Comment: I desperately don't know why :(

Comment: So now that your user has the correct permissions and the firewall rule allows traffic, next step is to check if the ssh service is running in the instance.

Run the following command to get the IP of the instance:
$ gcloud compute instances describe [NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE] --format='get(networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP)'

Install netcat => is a computer networking utility for reading/writing to network connections:
$ sudo apt-get install netcat

Run the following command to check the output of the command:
$ nc [EXTERNAL_IP] 22

Paste the output of the command above.

Comment: THanks, Nothing is return from running the command nc [EXTERNAL_IP] 22  so I guess ssh is not running on the instance right ?

Comment: I cannot SSH using the gcloud browser from the console so I guess you right my ssh is down. How can I start it up ? Thanks

Comment: Check if the Linux Guest Environment is enabled in your instance.
To do so, you should add an startup script on the GCE instance.

To add the startup script to the instance:
1. Click on the instance name
2. Click on edit
3. Go to the "custom metadata" section
4. In the "Key" text field add: startup-script
5. In the "Value" text field add:
#! /bin/bash
sudo systemctl list-unit-files | grep google | grep enabled
6. Save the changes

You can find more detailed info on startup scripts here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: Then restart the instance so to allow the script to execute.

Verify that the Linux Guest Environment scripts are installed and running.
To do so, check the output of the startup script in the serial log console from the GCE instance.
You can check the expected outputs for the different Operating Systems here:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#wgei_services

Comment: If the Linux Guest Environment is not installed, re-install it.
You can follow this documentation here to install the LGE: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/linux-guest-environment#installation_methods

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (Required 'compute.instances.get' permission for 'projects) and then I used the project id instead of the project name in the gcloud command and it worked. 
I assigned the 'Compute Instance Admin' role to the user, I used to login with gcloud.  This role includes the 'compute.instances.get' permission.

Answer (score 0):

Check your list of firewalls with the gcloud compute command-line tool and ensure the default-allow-ssh rule is present. See [troubleshooting-ssh](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules list
```

If the firewall rule is missing, add it

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create default-allow-ssh --allow tcp:22
```

Output:

```
Creating firewall...⠧Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/marketstore/global/firewalls/default-allow-ssh].
Creating firewall...done.
NAME               NETWORK  DIRECTION  PRIORITY  ALLOW   DENY  DISABLED
default-allow-ssh  default  INGRESS    1000      tcp:22        False
```